# How to extend the time displaying the launch picture of an iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, image

I have added a Default.png picture to my resource folder and the picture is now correctly displayed when the app is launched. But right now I have a problem that the time of the picture shown on screen is just too short and user just doesn't have enough time to take a look at the pic. And idea? Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Make a viewController with an imageView containing the launch image. Then have that viewController load first, and set it to change after some fixed amount of time.

Answer (score 2):

You could load the image onto the screen in the applicationDidFinishLaunching:withOptions method and then trigger a delay (using performSelector:afterDelay) to remove that image after a certain amount of time.  That doesn't help you have a consistent load screen time, since the actual load time will vary per device, but it does let you pad the load time a bit.

I suppose if you want to get really fancy, you could pad the load time varying amounts depending on the device.  Whatever you do I'd keep it to only an extra second or two.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should take a look at Apples description, [what the launch image is exactly for](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/BuildTimeConfiguration/BuildTimeConfiguration.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW12). I strongly recommend not to annoy the user with longer than needed "splash screens". Keep in mind, that there are people with devices, which don't support multi tasking. Using your app while getting text messages or other push notifications, switching to another app and back to yours is frustrating big time, if they have to wait until *you* think, they have payed enough attention to a (mostly) useless image.

Please, think about avoiding the use of nag screens. :)